Node.js: Application crashing with ‘Heap Out of Memory’ error
What are the best practices and tools for performing a memory profile on a React.js frontend and a Strapi backend application? How can I identify memory leaks, optimize memory usage, and ensure efficient resource management across both the frontend and backend?
Could you also provide a step-by-step guide or recommended tools for analyzing memory issues in these technologies? Are there any tools ?
